# C++ pull a card from deck

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a program that will pull a card from a deck of 52 regular playing cards.

- Suits: Heart, Spad, Diamond, Club.
- Rank: A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K.

This should be the output:

```
Let's pull a card!
This time we got AH
Wanna pull a card again?
y
This time we got 3J
Wanna pull a card again?
n
```

My output is:

```
Let's pull a card!
DKThis time we got 00
Wanna pull a card again?
n
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Function Declaration
int rankCard(), suitCard();

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    char answer;

    cout << "Let's pull a card!" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "This time we got " << rankCard() << suitCard() << endl;
        cout << "Wanna pull a card again?" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
    } while ((answer == 'y') || (answer == 'Y'));

    return 0;
}

int rankCard() {
    int rank = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    switch (rank) {
    case 1: cout << "A";
        break;
    case 10: cout << "T";
        break;
    case 11: cout << "J";
        break;
    case 12: cout << "Q";
        break;
    case 13: cout << "K";
        break;
    default: cout << rank;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int suitCard() {
    int suit = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    switch (suit) {
    case 1: cout << "H";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "D";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "C";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "S";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why the cards pulled (DK) are in that position and why I also get the 00. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Think about the return type of each function such as ```int suitCard()``` - should it be perhaps ```char suitCard()```? In that case, how would you change the ```cout``` and ```return``` statements in the functions?

Comment: `cout << "This time we got " << rankCard() << suitCard() << endl;` since rankCard and suitCard both return 0, they print 0.

Comment: Note: the output "This time we got 3J" seems incorrect as 'J' is not a suit.

Answer (score 2):

Your calls to `rankCard()` and `suitCard()` always return 0.

That `0` value is what's passed to `cout` in your main function.

The weird 'DK' is caused by the calls to `cout` inside `rankCard` and `suitCard`.

You could modify your functions to avoid the confusion:

```
#include <string>

std::string rankCard() {
    int rank = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    switch (rank) {
       case 1: return "A";
       case 10: return "T";
       case 11: return "J";
       case 12: return "Q";
       case 13: return "K";
       default: return std::to_string( rank );
    }
    return "";
}
std::string suitCard() {
    int suit = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    switch (suit) {
        case 1: return "H";
        case 2: return "D";
        case 3: return "C";
        case 4: return "S";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```c
cout << "This time we got " << rankCard() << suitCard() << endl;
```

So those functions print the card, and then they return 0, so if you call them in `cout`, they will do their thing witch is printing the card and then print the return value witch is 0.

What you can do is to  call them outside the `cout`, just do:

```c
//...
cout << "This time we got ";
rankCard();
suitCard(); 
cout << endl;
cout << "Wanna pull a card again?" << endl;
//...
```

Personally I would refactor the functions to return the respective card char:

[**Live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/rkBaHu4E8)

```c
const char rankCard() {
    int rank = (rand() % 13) + 1;
    switch (rank) {
    case 1: return 'A';
    case 10: return 'T';
    case 11: return 'J';
    case 12: return 'Q';
    case 13: return 'K';
    default: return rank + 48; // convert to decimal digit
    }   
}

const char suitCard() {
    int suit = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    switch (suit) {
    case 1: return 'H';
    case 2: return 'D';
    case 3: return 'C';
    case 4: return 'S';
    default: return 0;  //ASCII code for null character
    }
}
```